# Phone shuts off in 3g

Tags: battery, 3g, motorola

I have a Moto Z2 Play with Android 8.0.0, about 3 years old. Whenever I go out of range of 4g (to 3g), the battery goes from 100% to 80 or 70 in a couple minutes and then to single digits very quickly and the phone shuts down. The phone will not turn back on in this state. When I charge it, it returns to 70/80 immediately and it will turn back on. This never happens in 4g.

What is the problem? Is the battery just faulty?

--- follow up ---

I attached a power bank and went out. Here is what happened.

It lasted longer, perhaps an hour and then went to single digits and then turned off. I then restarted the phone with the power bank and it was quickly back up to full power.

What does this tell us?

Comment: Faulty battery cannot be ruled out but the problem looks with modem or RIL. In 3G mode it draws high surge current which the battery is unable to supply.

Comment: Try to get a power bank and connect it to your phone. If the problem persists the battery is not the main problem.

Comment: See edit to question for the follow up

Comment: It tells that your phone draws abnormally high amperage. Question is more about hardware and electronics than Android. But the root cause can be a bad RIL etc.

Comment: Sounds like time for a new phone.

Comment: I have a new phone now. What's the thing to do with this question? One of the comments could be turned into an answer. Or I could delete the question.

Comment: @AlLelopath you can answer your own question, it's encouraged.

Comment: @IrfanLatif: ok, but you are welcome to answer since you guided me in the right direction.